# Autofac pass list of string as parameter to constructor

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

I want to pass a list of string as constructor parameter. I used `web.config` to specify the interface and service binding. So I want to configure `web.config` to pass list of string parameter when initiate class. I used autofac as IOC. Could anybody help me on this?

Comment: Any particular reason why you use XML over code based configuration?

Comment: @Steven: +1 for the valid question here. If there is no need for XML based configuration it is easy to achieve this by code config. Anyway, I wrote the answer how to do this using XML.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a sample web.config with autofac configuration. The registration of `Autofac.Example.Calculator.Division.Divide` has a sample of how to specify parameters to a constructor.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="autofac" type="Autofac.Configuration.SectionHandler, Autofac.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>

<autofac defaultAssembly="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Api">
  <components>
    <component
      type="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Addition.Add, Autofac.Example.Calculator.Addition"
      service="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Api.IOperation" />
    <component
      type="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Division.Divide, Autofac.Example.Calculator.Division"
      service="Autofac.Example.Calculator.Api.IOperation"
      inject-properties="yes">
      <parameters>
        <parameter name="places" value="4" />
      </parameters>
      <properties>
        <property name="EnableExceptions" value="true" />
      </properties>
    </component>
  </components>
  <modules>
    <module type="CalculationModule" />
  </modules>
  <files>
    <file name="Controllers.config" section="controllers" />
    <file name="Services.config" />
  </files>
</autofac>
</configuration>
```

Further information about XML based configuration using AutoFac can be found in the [documentation here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html).

Comment: I think he was asking for a list of strings and not only simple strings. The documentation doesn't say anything about how to configure lists. The just show this for base types (strings, numbers) like in your example, too. So this is not really answering the question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure list in Autofac's XML configuration module to pass them as constructor parameters this way:

```
<component type="MyNameSpace.MyClass, MyAssemblyName">
  <parameters>
    <parameter name="myListParameter">
      <list>
        <item value="MyFirstItem"/>
        <item value="MySecondItem"/>
      </list>
    </parameter>
  </parameters>
</component>
```

This works for both Components and Modules and is (nearly) the same as doing this in Code:

```
var list = new List<string> { "MyFirstItem", "MySecondItem" };
var a = new MyNameSpace.MyClass(list);

// or explicitely with named parameter
var b = new MyNameSpace.MyClass(myListParameter: list);
```

Be aware that the parameter's name needs to match the one of your class constructor of MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public MyClass(IList<string> myListParameter)
  {
```